# How to use conditional different columns in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to use completely different conditions in a WHERE-clause in an SQL Server 2014 query, not just change the parameter.

I have the following clause

```
WHERE        (dbo.SecurityCheckUserInADGroups.CWID = @cwid2) AND (dbo.SecurityCheckUserInDatabaseRoles.Server = @server)
```

If the variable @cwid2 is NULL or empty I'd like to replace the whole first part of the AND-Statement with

```
dbo.SecurityCheckLDAPGroupName.DatabaseUserName = @role2
```

So here not only the parameter but also the column changes.

I tried If, Case and Iif with something like this, but it isn't accepted:

```
(IIF (LEN(@cwid1) > '0, 'dbo.SecurityCheckUserInADGroups.CWID = @cwid2','dbo.SecurityCheckLDAPGroupName.DatabaseUserName = @role2'))
```

It keeps telling me "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Use AND/OR instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CASE WHEN ISNULL(@cwid2,'') <> '' THEN 
      dbo.SecurityCheckUserInADGroups.CWID = @cwid2 ELSE 
      dbo.SecurityCheckLDAPGroupName.DatabaseUserName = @role2 
      END 
AND dbo.SecurityCheckUserInDatabaseRoles.Server = @server
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic logic:

```
WHERE ((@cwid <> '' AND dbo.SecurityCheckUserInADGroups.CWID = @cwid2) OR
       (COALESCE(@cwid, '') = '' AND dbo.SecurityCheckLDAPGroupName.DatabaseUserName = @role2)
      ) AND
      (dbo.SecurityCheckUserInDatabaseRoles.Server = @server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution would be

```
Where (@var is null and col1=val1)
   Or (@var is not null and col2=val2)
```

Because query optimizers can sometimes choke on OR, I tend to look for other solutions when performance could be an issue (large data sets, etc.) but the above might be worth trying first.

If you do need something more specific, the trick to iif logic is that it returns a value to compare, not a predicate to evaluate.  You could do something like

```
Where col1 = iif(@var is null, val1, col1)
  And col2 = iif(var is null, col2, val2)
```

The idea here is that your "don't care" cases - like the value of col2 when var is null - resolve as "always true". But there are cases (like when col1 or col2 could be NULL) where this specific solution Will fail.

Which is why the first approach is the most general